# Bouncy castle unable to load keystore from P12 file in 1.52 version under OSGi

Tags: java, bouncycastle

The following code gives Exception "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEPBEKey cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BCPBEKey". Does anybody knows what the problem is ?

```
  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", provider);
  @Cleanup
  FileInputStream keystoreInput = new FileInputStream(certFileName);

  keystore.load(keystoreInput, pwd.toCharArray());
```

EDITED:
The same code works with 1.51 version. The above mentioned problem appears only with 1.52 and under OSGi environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCEPBEKey does not exist in 1.52. It looks like there are different versions of Bouncy Castle in the class path.